# Can I convert grammar file created for java to one for javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, antlr, grammar

I want to create a grammar parser in javascript. Currently I have it done for java.And also grammar file , say - test.g , written to be executed with java. It contains all methods and import statements to be added. It will not work when I use it with javascript even though i change the language option to javascript. How can i convert it and make it javascript compatible?

Comment: You wrote it in Java. So you'll have to rewrite it in JavaScript. It's important to note that Java and JavaScript have basically nothing in common except for their names

Comment: ohh.. actually my grammer file consists of thousands of lines. And rewriting it will be a tedious task. so was hoping for some utility to convert

Comment: @winhowes - Similar names plus *very* similar and in some cases identical syntax for for, while, if/else, obj.prop and obj.method(), and ++ and - -  operators, etc. But other than all the ways in which they're alike they are completely different.

Comment: @nnnnnn yeah there are other similarities, but it's helpful to have them in two different mental categories. They're about as similar as `C` and `Java`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grammar rules are target independent (i.e. the same for Java, Python, C#, JavaScript, ...).

However, the embedded code (everything between `{ ... }`), including the code inside predicates (`{ ... }?`), ***is*** target dependent and will have to be re-written for the new target.